# Can a septic dispersal field be too big?

Tags: septic

When designing a septic dispersal field (via sub-surface dripline), can it be harmful for the field to be much larger than required?  E.g. not getting enough wastewater through to keep the drippers clear.

Our current (failed after 7 years) field was sized based on generous water usage, and double the actual house occupancy, and I'm wondering if this could be a factor in the failure.

Comment: what is the reason for failure?

Comment: I don't know in detail, other than the dispersal field is blocked, and the plumber hasn't been able to clear it with flushing and chlorine dosing.

Comment: perhaps you have problems with roots